# jQuery - Make action on each field in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make simple form validator on jQuery

```
$('#clients_name').keyup(function(){
    if($('#clients_name').val().length >= 2){
      (...)
    }
});
```

But I want check more inputs (text, select...) and I don't know how I should change the first line to make universal action "keyup" (or something) for any inputs in my form. This is good for input=text, but for select not...

```
$('input[type=text],select').keyup(function(){
    if($('#clients_name').val().length >= 2){
      (...)
    }
    if($('#clients_street').val().length >= 2){
      (...)
    }
});
```

Comment: does select have a `keyup` function? shouldnt you use `change` for select?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `This`

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){   // $('select,input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
      (...)
    }
    //Or can be
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
      (...)
    }
});
```

But `.keyup` will only works for the textboxes.You need to use .on('change',function(){..}) for either the select boxes and check,radio.

Comment: `this.value` would do i think.

Comment: we can use like this also

Comment: yes, i know. But its going to map internally to `this.value`, anyway. so why waste time doing this?

Comment: No no iam saying that ...we can use like you said and I mentioned in my ans also....thnx for the suggestion

Comment: oops. my bad..sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The context of `this` in the callback function passed to `.keyup()` will be set to the current DOM element. Simply reference `this`. But `select` elements don't trigger a `keyup` event. So I would change what you have there to:

```
$('input[type=text], select').on("change", function(){
    if(this.value.length >= 2){
      // do your validation
    }
});
```

Comment: But in "select" keyup don't work, right? And in radio too. I can't find universal action...